# for loop in javascript to get the values in select list

Tags: javascript, php, html, smarty, prestashop

I have a code where on select of category I am getting products fetched but I want those products to be shown in a select box. The code is inside a JavaScript.
My code is not working , I am using a for loop for showing products in select box.
my code is as follows :

```
<script>
    var abc = {
        $finprolist
    } // product list with category {4:bat,ball}

    function getid() {
        var e = document.getElementById("category");
        var cate = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; //onselect category id

        var check = abc[cate];
        alert(check); //getting products here based on category selected


        var productsfin = '';
        productsfin += '<option value="">Select Product</option>';

        for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
            productsfin += '<option value="' + check[i] + '">' + check[i] + '</option>';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Till alert (check) its working fine now I try to print those products in for loop to show inside select box its not working. Please help..

Comment: *My code is not working* - what is not working? Have you added that HTML string to DOM? If yes then how?

Comment: in var abc i am getting array like {4: bat, ball,chair} then i am using it inside javascript. @b0s3 i haven't added html string to DOM.

Comment: So what error you are getting? Try to log `productsfin` and see what you are getting.

Comment: actully i am not getting any error but nothing is printed not even select list.

Comment: Do you please place an alert inside for loop and check that is it working? Also please let me know what value it is displaying in alert for the check?

Comment: If the $finprolist contains `4:bat,ball,chair` then you will for sure have errors in the console since that is not valid object notation

Comment: no its not going inside a for loop. :(

Comment: And what is the value for the alert check ?

Comment: all product list for particular id

Comment: So please add this code after alert check : 

var checkArray = check.split(","); 

and use it in for loop checkArray instead of check

I think check is the string not an array that's why i think it is not working

Comment: actully var checkArray = check.split(","); also not working.

Comment: please let me know what it is displaying when we place alert(checkArray.length);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84638/discussion-between-solutionswithus-and-ketki-nimdeo).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code properly formatted:

```
var abc = {$finprolist} // product list with category {4:bat,ball}
function getid(){
    var e = document.getElementById("category");
    var cate = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;//onselect category id
    var check = abc[cate];
    alert (check);//getting products here based on category selected
    var productsfin = '';
    productsfin += '<option value="">Select Product</option>';
    for(var i=0;i< check.length;i++){
        productsfin +=  '<option value="' + check[i] + '">' + check[i] + '</option>';
    }
}
```

so if abc is `{4:"bat,ball,chair"}` then check should be:

```
check=abc[cate].split(',');
```

```js
abc={4:"bat,ball,chair"}

check=abc[4].split(',');

var productsfin = '';
productsfin += '<option value="">Select Product</option>';
for(var i=0;i< check.length;i++){
    productsfin +=  '<option value="' + check[i] + '">' + check[i] + '</option>';
}
alert (productsfin);
```

I'm still not sure you are defining abc correctly.  it should generally be more like `abc=$finprolist`  rather than abc={$finprolist} or  `abc=[$finprolist]`

In the second case, the check would be `check=abc[0][cate].split(',')`

Comment: abc is like this : {"4":"bat,ball,chair","86":"ballon,chair1}  and abc[cate] gets only bat,ball ,chair on select of 4. i just need to get this products in for loop to show then in select list. and that for loop code has some problem.

Answer (score -1):

What's that ?

```
var abc = {$finprolist} // product list with category {4:bat,ball}
```

It really seems incorrect.

I don't know what are you doing here but it look like melting PHP and javascript, so it could be :

```
var abc = {<?php echo $finprolist; ?>} // product list with category {4:bat,ball}
```

BUT : the variable $finprolist has to be a string in JSON

Comment: its calling a php array in tpl file in prestashop. its correct i just need how can i get products in select box inside javascript.

Comment: Oh, that's a smarty code for prestashop. I understand, you need to precise it next time.